# how to make sure a bean is passed to the jsp from a servlet

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, javabeans

I have created a servlet which creates and populates the values of a bean and also sets the bean as a session attribute and passes it to the jsp file. But when I retrieve the bean using the session object, I get null value. The jsp has been designed in such a way that the items from the database are saved in the bean file and passed to the jsp file which displays the database/bean values.
This is in the doPost() method of the servlet:

```
        //Adding the list bean to the session
        session.setAttribute("list", list);
```

This is in the jsp file:

```
<%
MessageList list = (MessageList) request.getAttribute("list");
//The bean is of type 'MessageList'
%>
```

Comment: Show some code please, particularly where you place the object in the session and where you retrieve it.

Comment: @bdares the above is the comment

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the session, but you're retrieving from the request object.  Either change the second bit to `session.getAttribute("list")`, or change the first bit to `request.setAttribute("list", list)`